# favorite items first in google - having multiple favorites

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts

hi can you check over what i've tried to do with the multiple favorites? I can't seem to get it working...

```
var title_regexp = [/^.+- Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia$/, /^.+- Stack Overflow$/, /^.+- W3Schools$/];
var addr_regexp = [/^\w+\.wikipedia\.org\/.*$/, /^stackoverflow\.com\/.*$/, /^www\.w3schools\.com\/.*$/];
var mark_style = 'background-color: #CCFF99 !important; padding: 0.5em; -moz-border-radius: 0.5em';
var match_pattern = [3,3,3];
```

and the rest is untouched.

thank you for your help

the original document is at http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/55641

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs and code for [that script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/55641), `match_pattern` should be an integer, not an array. :

```
var match_pattern = 3;
```